# Automatic goto in texstudio 2.8

Tags: texstudio

I recently changed to texstudio and have been enjoying since. Since I updated the version to 2.8 every time I change the cursor in the tex the viewer also changes and viceversa. I'd rather having to press ctrl+click for this to happen, how can I change it to the previous behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PDF viewer, click *Configure* --> *Scrolling follows cursor*, and *Cursor follows scrolling*.

Answer (score 6):

You can also toggle this behavior using the two lock buttons in the status bar of the pdf viewer.

Comment: This solved it for me. I didn't notice those buttons and somehow, I can't see the configuration setting to check or uncheck the option. Maybe they removed it version 2.12.22